# FactoryGirl association with reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, factory-bot

I have four models: `User`, `Product`, `Ownership` and `Location`. `User`and `Product` have one `Location`, and `Location` belongs to `User` and to `Product` (Polymorphic model).

I want to use `FactoryGirl` to create products that have the same location as their owner.

```rb
factory :location do
  sequence(:address) { |n| "#{n}, street, city" }
end

factory :user do
  sequence(:name)  { |n| "Robot #{n}" }
  sequence(:email) { |n| "numero#{n}@robots.com"}
  association :location, factory: :location
end

factory :product do
  sequence(:name) { |n| "Objet #{n}" }
  association :location, factory: :location
end

factory :ownership do
  association :user, factory: :user
  association :product, factory: :product
end
```

I created a method in the **product model file** to retrieve the product's owner just by doing `product.owner`.

I want to adapt the **product factory** in order to replace the factoried location by `product.owner.location`. How can I do that?

### EDIT 1

I want to use it like that:

First I create a user

```rb
FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

Later I create a product

```rb
FactoryGirl.create(:product)
```

When I associate both of them

```rb
FactoryGirl.create(:current_ownership, product: product, user: user)
```

I want that the location of my product becomes the one of his owner.

Comment: So Product model has a belongs_to association to Owner?

Answer (score 11):

use the following code.

```
factory :user do
  sequence(:name)  { |n| "Robot #{n}" }
  sequence(:email) { |n| "numero#{n}@robots.com"}
  association :location, factory: :location

  factory :user_with_product do
    after(:create) do |user|
      create(:product, location: user.location)
    end
  end
end
```

To create the records, just use the `user_with_product` factory.

UPDATE:

In response to your question update, you can add an `after(:create)` callback to the `ownership` factory

```
factory :ownership do
  association :user, factory: :user
  association :product, factory: :product

  after(:create) do |ownership|
    # update ownership.user.location here with ownership.user.product
  end
end
```

The problem with this is your current association setup.  Since `location` belongs to user or product, the foreign key is in location. so a `location` can't both belong to a user and a product at the same time.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do the opposite. When I create a product, I want to be able to associate him with a user through the Ownership model, and in doing so, affect the `user.location` to my `product.location`... I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

using an `after_create` [callback](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#callbacks) should do the trick

```
factory :ownership do
  user # BONUS - as association and factory have the same name, save typing =)
  product
  after(:create) { |ownership| ownership.product.location = ownership.user.location }
end
```